# Regarding the use of Ampere's Law

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

i wanted to calculate $\mathbf{B}$ of these two parallel wires, and i've taken a glance at the correction and i've found out this equation, i tried to understand it but in vain, where do $(x + \frac{d}{2})$ and $(x - \frac{d}{2})$ come from? also why is the infinitesimal element is the vector product of $(\mathbf{e}_z \times \mathbf{e}_x)$ and not $(\mathbf{e}_x \times \mathbf{e}_z)$?

Any help even an advice is extremely appreciated. 
I can link the whole assignement for more clarification.
Many thanks.

[image: Schematics of the two parallel wires]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For an area vector between the wires in the direction of the B field, ez x ex is correct for a cross product in a right handed system.  I think the given expression for Bx is incorrect (assuming e is a unit vector pointing from the origin to P). It appears they used the tangent of the angle (between r and x) instead of the sine.